# Why is the largest invariant factor the minimal polynomial, and why is the product of invariant factors the characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

I'm just learning the primary decomposition theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID, and its application to linear algebra. Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$, and let $T: V \to V$ be a $K$-linear operator. We can then view $V$ as a $K[T]$-module, and we have that
$$
V \cong K[T]/(f_1(T)) \oplus \cdots \oplus K[T]/(f_n(T)),
$$
where $f_i$ divides $f_{i+1}$. Assume the $f_i$ are monic. My understanding is that $f_n$ is $T$'s minimal polynomial, and $f_1 f_2 \cdots f_n$ is $T$'s characteristic polynomial. How come this is the case?

Comment: I think you mean that $f_n$ is the minimal polynomial

Comment: Yep you're right, edited.

Comment: The minimal polynomial is easy to verify if you use the definition of the minimal polynomial directly. For the characteristic polynomial, the necessary fact is that the characteristic polynomial of a direct sum of linear maps is the product of each characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Does that clear everything up or are you looking for a more thorough explanation?

Comment: Yes I think that does it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @BenGrossmann Could you expand on "by definition of minimal polynomial"? I am still a bit lost. Thank you!

Comment: @orangecat The minimal polynomial is the lowest-degree monic polynomial $\mu$ such that $\mu(T) = 0$. On the other hand, for a polynomial $g(x)$, we will have $g(T) = 0$ for $T \in K[T]/f(T)$ if and only if $f\mid g$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Ah yes thank you!